# Adding a user in Active Directory using dsadd

Tags: active-directory

Here's a screenshot of my topology:

[image]

I'd like to use the dsadd command to add a user to Mercotel A> Administracion> Usuarios OU, but I can't figure out the syntax for nested OU's.

What would the command be?

```
dsadd user “cn=Sergio Tapia,ou=Mercotel A/Administracion/Usuarios,dc=aso,dc=com” -disabled no –pwd 123456 -mustchpwd no
```

This gives me an error.

Comment: The path to that OU would be "OU=Usuarios,OU=Administracion,OU=Mercotel A,DC=aso,DC=com".

Comment: This might help: http://www.aprendeinformaticaconmigo.com/windows-server-2008-crear-grupos-con-dsadd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user's DN should be:

"CN=Sergio Tapia,OU=Usuarios,OU=Administracion,OU=Mercotel A,DC=aso,DC=com"

Microsoft details the naming convention: *"A DN is a sequence of relative distinguished names (RDN) connected by commas"* in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366101%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Full command:

```
dsadd user "CN=Sergio Tapia,OU=Usuarios,OU=Administracion,OU=Mercotel A,DC=aso,DC=com" -disabled no -pwd 123456 -mustchpwd no
```

Comment: When I run this, I get an error that says pwd is unrecognized parameter. dsadd user "CN=Sergio Tapia,OU=Usuarios,OU=Administracion,OU=Mercotel A,DC=aso,DC=com" -disabled no –pwd 123456 -mustchpwd no

Comment: @Sergio: I had copied your original code, looks like it containted a '–' instead of a '-' on the `pwd` attribute. I have updated my answer with the "correct" dash. :)

Comment: There's TWO different dash symbols? :S

Comment: @Sergio: [There are *many* dashes](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/dashes.html).  The wrong dash '–' is EN DASH, the correct dash '-' is HYPHEN-MINUS. Software as Office [and blogging software] will sometimes "prettify" dashes and quotes, incorrectly, to make the characters appear nicer on-screen. This can cause issues when copy/pasting code.